# Newbie to Magento 1.9 Website with Questions

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

I just took on working on an existing website that is using the 1.9 version of Magento. I am trying to update the "About Us" pages and other pages on the website, but for some reason, when I go to edit the pages, they do not exist in the CMS page manager in the admin side of the website. When I do try to create a new page and link the new URL into the navigation menu area, my changes to not appear and it stays in the original condition.

This website was worked on by a professional developer before. Is it possible that these missing CMS pages are on a different local environment? I just feel stuck trying to edit this website when I can't make changes and important pages are missing... Can anyone help this newbie??

Comment: Does the content exist in a CMS block? Is about us in the main menu? If yes, the content could live in the category settings. Do you see references from the About Us page in your code repository?

Comment: Found it in the static blocks! Thank you so much!